# Should a new tag be created for FTL: Advanced Edition?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question about FTL:AE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162866/what-does-manning-sensor-stations-do) was recently asked, and marked as a duplicate of [this one about FTL classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73964/what-are-the-benefits-of-manning-a-subsystem).

Should a new tag be created such as `ftl-advanced-edition` for these types of questions, or should questions related to "classic" FTL be edited to reflect the new Advanced Edition content?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: the 'AE' changes are applied to all copies of FTL if you just go online and download the patch, right? They don't require a desperate purchase? If so, then our general policy is to not create a new tag for what amounts to a content patch.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yep, it's a free expansion/DLC/whathaveyou.  That said, there *is* an option to turn it off when you start a new game.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

FTL: Advanced Edition [does not seem to be a DLC or expansion - it's just a big content update](http://steamcommunity.com/games/212680/announcements/detail/1769094756731158442) to the base game so you should update existing questions and answers instead of adding new ones. I don't think there's a need for a new tag for it.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  Advanced content can be disabled, so you can play the game without any of the new stuff.

Comment: It seems more like an advanced difficulty setting than anything else..

Comment: @GnomeSlice I'm not sure either, but if we go with this answer, it sounds like each question and answer will require some additional depth to reflect both editions. (i.e. good answers will include statements like "if you're playing the classic edition, then X, but if you're playing the advanced edition, then Y")

Comment: @Mike Except the vast majority of answers will either be the same for both, or will only apply to the advanced version's new content.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft well, that's kind of why I posed the question. Is that an argument for tagging them separately if they have differentiators?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ah, I see you closed the question. Sounds like we have a decision, then.

Comment: My question has been closed twice, who re-opened it and why? Which way are we ruling on this?

Comment: @Ender [Fredley](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/162866/revisions)

Comment: @Mike. If an answer does not address the new content, leave a comment for the answerer to update, or failing that, start a bounty on the question

Comment: I'm not sure the *vast majority of questions* will apply to both identically; there really is a ton of content changed and the difficulty is only slightly harder (given the same difficulty level, not including hard mode which is also new.)  Probably the slight majority with be identical to both, IMO.

Comment: [Wiki page describing the update](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/FTL:_Advanced_Edition)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a method for dealing with questions that need an update due to a major change in the game: offering a bounty.  There's even a bounty reason specifically for this occasion.

> **Current answers are outdated** 
>   The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

This should cover all the questions that are 'no longer relevant' due to the update, and any questions specific to update content can be addressed by individual questions.

Comment: Yeah, but bounties imply I have rep to spend. ;-)

Comment: @Mike You can post bounties on another person's question - the idea being that high-rep users who see a question that needs an update will be generous and offer one.